# Remove Bullets from dataframe R

Tags: r, database, gsub

I have a Data Frame which is having bullets `•` in the data. I would like to remove them from them data before processing.

I tried `gsub` but there is no hope

`df <- data.frame(apply(Import, 2, function(x) {
     x <- gsub("\• ", "", x)
})
)`

Is there a way to remove it

Comment: may i know the reason for down vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works just fine on some sample data I created.

```
# Sample data
df <- cbind.data.frame(
    col1 = paste0("•", LETTERS[1:10]),
    col2 = paste0(LETTERS[11:20], "•"));


as.data.frame(sapply(df, function(x) gsub("•", "", x)))
#   col1 col2
#1     A    K
#2     B    L
#3     C    M
#4     D    N
#5     E    O
#6     F    P
#7     G    Q
#8     H    R
#9     I    S
#10    J    T
```

Comment: No worries @PraveenDA; glad to help.